# Tkinter . grid isn't changing position of widget

Tags: python-3.x

[Window that is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWX27.png)

```
def InputComp(Mainframe):
    Tk.destroy(Mainframe)
    InputCompet = Frame(Main , width = 600 , height = 600)
    InputCompet.config(bg = 'grey')
    Firstname=Label(InputCompet,text='FirstName',bg='grey').grid(row=0,column = 0)
    FirstnameInput = Entry(InputCompet).grid(row = 0 , column = 10)

    Secondname = Label(InputCompet , text = 'Surname',bg = 'grey').grid(row = 2 , 
    column = 0)
    SecondnameInput = Entry(InputCompet).grid(row = 2 , column = 10)

    InputCompet.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
```

When ever i change the row and column in the .grids it doesn't change the position unless another widget is is a row or column behind it, but in that case it only moves i one row/column